# Remove check box in List View for specific items

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm using the following code to remove the check box next to a specific item in my List View:

```
LVITEM lvI;

lvI.iItem = i;
lvI.mask = LVIF_STATE;
lvI.stateMask = LVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK;
lvI.state = 0;

SendMessage(hListOutput, LVM_SETITEM, 0, (LPARAM) &lvI);
```

It works, but if I click where the check box used to be it re-appears!

How can I remove the check box on a specific item in my list view, and keep it removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the desired state of the check box in a variable (default null). In the check box changed event, if that variable is not null flip the state to the saved value.

Comment: Gonna accept this as the answer, since it gave me the idea to work it out. Should note that you have to check `LVN_ITEMCHANGING` in `WM_NOTIFY` and check if `uOldState` is 0 or not, as well as save the state somewhere.